# Is there a reason Gotou and Menthuthuyoupi look so similar?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, parasyte

Is there a correlation between these two characters? I was wondering if the same illustrator drew both characters or if perhaps one of them was sort of a homage to the other. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here are some possible answer you might get a) Author influence b) Limit in number of designs, so finding 2 characters with similar design is normal (birthday paradox) c) Tracing (very unlikely)

Comment: This is likely just cooincedince and an aglomeration of features that seem tough/serious (sharp features, strong jawline, tight lips, narrow intense eyes)..  Nevertheless +1 for noticing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just referencing [nhahtdh's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/25883/is-there-a-reason-gotou-and-menthuthuyoupi-look-so-similar/27893#comment36014_25883) as the answer since it seems he does not want to post it as an answer.

But the reason that there could be similar character design in two different animes could be due to:

> 1. Author Influence
> 2. Limit in number of designs([birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem))
> 3. Tracing(unlikely)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both characters are rather similar.
They both were extraordinry beings, created by not one, but multiple creatures. Both tend to find interest in Humanity but wont lose sight of their goals, I'm sure there are even more similarities between them

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on your answer, preferably by citing sources to support your claims? 'I'm sure there are even more similarities between them' The OP is not sure so if there are even more similarities, then list and explain them.